# Proof of sub-additivity for Shannon Entropy

Tags: probability, entropy

in [A Mathematical Theory of Communication (CE Shannon, 1948)](http://math.harvard.edu/~ctm/home/text/others/shannon/entropy/entropy.pdf), the entropy of a categorical random variable is defined as:
$$H(X)=-\sum_{i}P(X=i)\log P(X=i)$$
while the joint entropy of two such variables is defined as:
$$H(X,Y)=-\sum_{i,j}P(X=i,Y=j)\log P(X=i,Y=j)$$
Then it is stated (p.12) that "It is easily shown that":
$$H(X,Y)\leq H(X)+H(Y)$$
with equality for independence.

I believe this property is referred to as sub-additivity, and I'm wondering what this "easy" way to prove it might be.

What I have tried so far:

I believe, using the Law of Total Probability, we can get 
$H(X)+H(Y)=-\sum_{i,j}P(X=i,Y=j)\log (P(X=)P(Y=j))$ which would establish the equality for independence, but I don't know how to get the inequality. That would seem to require $P(X=i,Y=j)\leq P(X=i)P(Y=i)$ which is not always true.

[I've found a source](https://www3.nd.edu/~dgalvin1/pdf/Kalamazoo_entropy.pdf) that proves the inequality using two other properties (*Chain Rule* and *Dropping the Conditional*). But these are introduced later in Shannon's paper so can't be the "easy" proof he had in mind?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Define the relative entropy (or Kulback-Leibler divergence) of the probabilities $P$ and $Q$, with $P\ll Q$, as 
$$D(P\|Q) = \sum_{x\in \Omega} p(x) \log \frac{p(x)}{q(x)}. $$
Using the inequality $\log a \leq a-1,$ for $ a>0$, it is easy to show that
$$D(P\|Q) \geq 0.$$
(Just take  $a=\frac{q(x)}{p(x)}$ with $p(x)>0$).

But then
\begin{align}
H(X)+H(Y) - H(X,Y) &= \sum_{x,y\in \Omega} p(x,y)\log \frac{p(x,y)}{p_X(x)p_Y(y)}  \\
&=D(P_{X,Y}\| P_X \otimes P_Y)\\
& \geq 0.
\end{align}
where $P_X$ and $P_Y$ are the marginal distributions of $X$ and $Y$, and the equality holds if $X,Y$ are independent.

Comment: Note that the quantity $I(X;Y)=H(X)+H(Y)-H(X,Y)$ is also known as the **mutual information** of $X$ and $Y$ and is always nonnegative, and is equal to zero iff $X$ and $Y$ are independent.