# Shannon's proof that joint entropy is less or equal to the sum of marginal entropies

Tags: probability, information-theory, entropy

I am reading Shannon's famous paper and I stuck on "It is easily shown that" part. More precisely I mean the inequality $$H(X, Y)\leq H(X) + H(Y),$$
where $X, Y$ are some discrete random variables. Following the paper we have that
$$H(X,Y)=-\sum_{ij}p(i, j)\log(p(i,j)) \\ 
H(X)=-\sum_{ij}p(i, j)\log\left(\sum_{k}p(i,k)\right) \\
H(Y)=-\sum_{ij}p(i, j)\log\left(\sum_{l}p(l,j)\right)$$
And if we sum $H(X) + H(Y)$ we get that
$$H(X) + H(Y) = -\sum_{ij}p(i, j)\log(p(i)p(j)).$$
And this is where I stuck. It is obvious from the above that if $X,Y$ are independent then the equality holds. However, the inequality is a different story. In general $p(i,j)$ and $p(i)p(j)$ are incomparable by simple inequality, thus some other methods must be used.

What is the most straightforward proof of this inequality? (Or if one knows, what proof Shannon had in mind?). Shannon states the inequality before defining conditional entropy $H_X(Y)$ so I suspect that it in fact this should be easy... or did he lie?

Comment: closely related https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3326158/532409

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rearrange the inequality so that one side is zero. Write the other side as a single sum over $i$ and $j$. Use the facts that the sum of two logs is the log of a product, and the difference of two logs is the log of a quotient to replace the three logarithmic terms by a single one. Use convexity of the logarithm.

EDIT:
To explain the convexity part, consider that the graph of $\log_a x$ is concave down, for $a>1$. It follows that for all $x_1, x_2 > 0$ and all $s_1, s_2 \in [0,1]$ such that $s_1+s_2=1$, we have that $s_1 \log_a x_1 + s_2 \log_a x_2 \leq \log_a (s_1 x_1 + s_2 x_2)$. This inequality can be extended by induction from $2$ $x$ and $s$ pairs to $n$.
In our case, the $p(i,j)$ play the role of the $s_i$.

EDIT 2: The above yields a bound of $\log_a 1$, i.e. of zero.

Comment: I did what you said and I obtain:
$$H(X,Y)-H(X)-H(Y)=\sum_{i,j}p(i,j)\log(\frac{\sum_{k}p(i,k) \sum_{l}p(l,j)}{p(i,j)})$$ which can be also simplified to $$\sum_{i,j}p(i,j)\log(\frac{p(i)p(j)}{p(i,j)}).$$
And I am stuck at the same spot as in my OP. I do not see how to use convexity here. I would be grateful if you could be more specific.

Comment: It works!
$$H(X,Y)-H(X)-H(Y)=\sum_{ij}p(i, j)\log\left(\frac{p(i)p(j)}{p(i,j)}\right)\leq\log\left(\sum_{ij}p(i,j)\frac{p(i)p(j)}{p(i,j)}\right) \\ = \log\left(\sum_{ij}p(i)p(j)\right)=\log(1)=0$$

Comment: Yay ! It seems that "easily" in mathematical writing doesn't mean the same as it means in everyday life. I think it means "Do-able without having to use recently published theorems or theorems with very long and complicated proofs".

Comment: Yeah. It is easy when you already know the answer :p

Comment: Exactly !! XD I suppose that also, after having seen the same tools used in such ways several times, then one can begin to guess correctly how things should go.

Comment: PS, it's a good exercise, to write out a careful proof that we have equality if, and only if, $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Comment: Hmm. I believe it boils down to the logarithm being strictly concave. If equality holds then all components $\frac{p(i)p(j)}{p(i,j)}$ must equal. They couldn't be greater nor less then 1, because it would violate that $p(i)p(j)$ is a probability. Thus $p(i)p(j)=p(i,j)$.

Comment: Yes, it's about the strict concavity of the log. Is $p_ip_j$ necessarily a probability ? Other than in the sense of being a real number between 0 and 1 ? I mean, must it be the probability of some event in this experiment ? Here is a version (pg 7), which also deals with the annoying cases in which $p(i,j)=0$: https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.08731

Comment: $p_ip_j$ is precisely [the product of probability measures](http://theanalysisofdata.com/probability/F_4.html#MathJax-Element-109-Frame) in the discrete case. Since $p_ip_j$'s sum to 1, they may be interpreted as probabilities. More specifically, it is the probability of "$i$ and $j$ events" treated as they are independent.
Yeah, it is annoying when impossible event happens :p

Comment: Good point !! Nicely put - thanks.